# Invalid Form Key when users login to my site

Tags: magento2

I'm relatively new to Magento, and I need some help.
We're on Magento2, and we just upgraded from Magento 1.x.
Whenever our users come to our site and click login they are taken to a subsite for registered customers.
(e.g. mysite.com --> dealer.mysite.com)
When they enter their credentials they get an Invalid Form Key error.  They can ignore the error, re-enter their credentials and successfully, login on their 2nd try.
This is driving a ton of calls to our help desk, and the team is struggling to figure out how to resolve it.
I've looked up the error, and everything points to admins getting it, not the customers.  I'm having no problem with it when logging into our admin site.

We also have a staging site on our domain, and it isn't having the problem.
Like I said, I'm relatively new to magento, so detailed guidance is most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the cookie settings of your websites. Since you are using the same domain for multiple websites, I would suggest you set the cookie domain as "mysite.com" in *Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings > Cookie Domain* configuration for each of the websites.